# django mysql not run in macOS Big Sur

Tags: mysql, sql, django, macos

Some trouble after Big Sur update

I use Django 2.1.15 and Python 3.8

according to posts and documentation I installed the connector

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

and

```
pip install mysql-python
```

after I install mysql

```
 brew install mysql
```

and the client

```
 pip install mysqlclient
```

try to run django and i get this ERROR:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 54")
```

This is my setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'BATABASE',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.10',
        'PORT': '1433',
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this https://github.com/imagineai/create-django-app

npm install -g imagine && imagine create -f django -n myapp

It will auto-detect your Python version and install appropriate dependencies. You can also select the database you want in the im file.